# How to authenticate the Slack app for an API call?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

Ok, so, normally I won't ask such a -on the surface- simple question, but I *really* don't understand Slack's authentication scheme.

My question is super simple, I just want to do: `user_list = client.users_list()`

My question? How do I authenticate?

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient

client = WebClient() # <== ???????

user_list = client.users_list()

print(user_list)
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install](https://api.slack.com/authentication/basics#installing) the app to a workspace before you can get an access token, which is what you'll use to authenticate your app to the API.

If you're installing it on a single workspace, there's a button you can click in your app's configuration page, but if you're installing it across multiple workspaces, you'll need to build out an [OAuth flow](https://api.slack.com/authentication/oauth-v2).

Comment: Thanks – I'll give this route a go